# Get JSON array object at index satisfying a filter condition using jq

Tags: jq

I need to get the entire object(s) in json array returned by `list-action-executions` command from aws cli, where the attributes satisfy the condition below

```
"stageName": "DeployStage",
"actionName": "PromoteToProdApprovalGate",
```

The output from the awscli command is of the format.  The actual output contains about 40 array elements and more than 1 satisfying the above conditions.  I would like to get all of them as full objects.  How can I do it with JQ?  I tried the select and index options, but was not successful.

How should my jq query be formatted?

Thank you

```
{
  "actionExecutionDetails": [
    {
      "pipelineExecutionId": "pipeline-exec-id-1",
      "actionExecutionId": "action-exec-id-1",
      "pipelineVersion": 2,
      "stageName": "DeployStage",
      "actionName": "PromoteToProdApprovalGate",
      "startTime": "2020-06-01T22:11:53-04:00",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2020-06-01T22:11:53-04:00",
      "status": "InProgress",
      "input": {
        "actionTypeId": {
          "category": "Approval",
          "owner": "AWS",
          "provider": "Manual",
          "version": "1"
        },
        "configuration": {
          "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_COMMIT_ID}",
          "ExternalEntityLink": "#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_URL}",
          "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
        },
        "resolvedConfiguration": {
          "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=bb-commit-id-1",
          "ExternalEntityLink": "url/bb-commit-id",
          "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
        },
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "inputArtifacts": []
      },
      "output": {
        "outputArtifacts": [],
        "outputVariables": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "pipelineExecutionId": "pipeline-exec-id-2",
      "actionExecutionId": "action-exec-id-2",
      "pipelineVersion": 2,
      "stageName": "DeployStage",
      "actionName": "ImageEnvironmentTag",
      "startTime": "2020-06-01T22:09:45.833000-04:00",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2020-06-01T22:11:52.689000-04:00",
      "status": "Succeeded",
      "input": {
        "actionTypeId": {
          "category": "Build",
          "owner": "AWS",
          "provider": "CodeBuild",
          "version": "1"
        },
        "configuration": {
          "EnvironmentVariables": "[\n  { \"name\": \"LAST_ENV\", \"value\": \"qa\" },\n  { \"name\": \"BB_COMMIT_ID\", \"value\": \"#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_COMMIT_ID}\" }\n]\n",
          "ProjectName": "project-name-environement-tag"
        },
        "resolvedConfiguration": {
          "EnvironmentVariables": "[\n  { \"name\": \"LAST_ENV\", \"value\": \"qa\" },\n  { \"name\": \"BB_COMMIT_ID\", \"value\": \"bb-commit-id-1\" }\n]\n",
          "ProjectName": "projectName"
        },
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "inputArtifacts": [
          {
            "name": "PipelineArtifacts",
            "s3location": {
              "bucket": "bucket",
              "key": "key"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "output": {
        "outputArtifacts": [],
        "executionResult" : {
          "externalExecutionId": "externalExecutionId",
          "externalExecutionUrl": "https://console.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/home?region=us-east-1#/builds/"
        },
        "outputVariables": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "pipelineExecutionId": "",
      "actionExecutionId": "",
      "pipelineVersion": 2,
      "stageName": "DeployStage",
      "actionName": "PromoteToProdApprovalGate",
      "startTime": "2020-06-01T22:11:53-04:00",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2020-06-01T22:11:53-04:00",
      "status": "InProgress",
      "input": {
        "actionTypeId": {
          "category": "Approval",
          "owner": "AWS",
          "provider": "Manual",
          "version": "1"
        },
        "configuration": {
          "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_COMMIT_ID}",
          "ExternalEntityLink": "#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_URL}",
          "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
        },
        "resolvedConfiguration": {
          "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=xxx1",
          "ExternalEntityLink": "http://",
          "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
        },
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "inputArtifacts": []
      },
      "output": {
        "outputArtifacts": [],
        "outputVariables": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "pipelineExecutionId": "",
      "actionExecutionId": "",
      "pipelineVersion": 1,
      "stageName": "DeployStage",
      "actionName": "PromoteToProdApprovalGate",
      "startTime": "2020-03-31T23:29:14.479000-04:00",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2020-04-03T19:04:51.646000-04:00",
      "status": "Succeeded",
      "input": {
        "actionTypeId": {
          "category": "Approval",
          "owner": "AWS",
          "provider": "Manual",
          "version": "1"
        },
        "configuration": {
          "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_COMMIT_ID}",
          "ExternalEntityLink": "#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_URL}",
          "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
        },
        "resolvedConfiguration": {
          "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=xxx2",
          "ExternalEntityLink": "http://",
          "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
        },
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "inputArtifacts": []
      },
      "output": {
        "outputArtifacts": [],
        "executionResult": {
          "externalExecutionId": ",
          "externalExecutionSummary": "Approved by arn:aws:sts:"
        },
        "outputVariables": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "pipelineExecutionId": "",
      "actionExecutionId": "",
      "pipelineVersion": 1,
      "stageName": "DeployStage",
      "actionName": "PromoteToProdApprovalGate",
      "startTime": "2020-03-18T21:10:25.541000-04:00",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2020-03-25T21:10:25.965000-04:00",
      "status": "Failed",
      "input": {
        "actionTypeId": {
          "category": "Approval",
          "owner": "AWS",
          "provider": "Manual",
          "version": "1"
        },
        "configuration": {
          "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_COMMIT_ID}",
          "ExternalEntityLink": "#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_URL}",
          "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1"
        },
        "resolvedConfiguration": {
          "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=xxx3",
          "ExternalEntityLink": "http://",
          "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
        },
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "inputArtifacts": []
      },
      "output": {
        "outputArtifacts": [],
        "executionResult": {
          "externalExecutionId": ""
        },
        "outputVariables": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "pipelineExecutionId": "",
      "actionExecutionId": "",
      "pipelineVersion": 1,
      "stageName": "DeployStage",
      "actionName": "PromoteToProdApprovalGate",
      "startTime": "2020-03-09T19:23:43.637000-04:00",
      "lastUpdateTime": "2020-03-10T14:48:30.069000-04:00",
      "status": "Failed",
      "input": {
        "actionTypeId": {
          "category": "Approval",
          "owner": "AWS",
          "provider": "Manual",
          "version": "1"
        },
        "configuration": {
          "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_COMMIT_ID}",
          "ExternalEntityLink": "#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_URL}",
          "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1"
        },
        "resolvedConfiguration": {
          "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=xxx4",
          "ExternalEntityLink": "http://",
          "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
        },
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "inputArtifacts": []
      },
      "output": {
        "outputArtifacts": [],
        "executionResult": {
          "externalExecutionId": "",
          "externalExecutionSummary": ""
        },
        "outputVariables": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Post the options you have attempted

Comment: I tried this `.actionExecutionDetails[].actionName  | select ( index("PromoteToProdApprovalGate") )` based on some examples i had seen and it returns `"PromoteToProdApprovalGate"` 4 instances from my full json, but I want to get the complete object that contains the above filter and also I want to add one more filter of stage name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely mistake people tend to do with `jq` on such situations is to use the `select()` function to the entire JSON itself which would *not* work as expected. The right filter would be to filter on the array

```
.actionExecutionDetails[]
| select(.stageName == "DeployStage" and .actionName == "PromoteToProdApprovalGate")'
```

See it working on [jq-play](https://jqplay.org/s/WNoq3_lruM)

Or if you want the original array updated with the filtered result, do this

```
.actionExecutionDetails |= 
map(select(.stageName == "DeployStage" and .actionName == "PromoteToProdApprovalGate"))
```

---

As for why your original attempt *didn't* work,

```
.actionExecutionDetails[].actionName 
| select ( index("PromoteToProdApprovalGate") )
```

the path expression to get the objects list is *wrong*. You are basically selecting on the `.actionName` string field which when used with `select(index(..))` returns a bool value true, causing your string to repeat for each match condition.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Can you help me with one more part?  If I want to get the object that has last / latest value for   `"startTime": ` -  how can I get that?  How do I add it to the above query?        Also, thank you for explaining issues with the original query.  I am trying to learn jq and mostly been getting the info by searching on net.  Do you know, if there is any do and learn kind of site / tutorial for JQ