# Get JSON array object with an attribute having latest timestamp

Tags: timestamp, max, jq

I was able to get the array elements satisfying a set of filters from output of list-action-executions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235507/jq-get-json-array-object-at-index-satisfying-a-filter-condition-using-jq/) question  Of the returned objects, how can I select the object that has latest value for `lastUpdateTime` attribute

This is the format of input that will be available from the output of the linked question

```
{
  "pipelineExecutionId": "",
  "actionExecutionId": "",
  "pipelineVersion": 2,
  "stageName": "DeployStage",
  "actionName": "PromoteToProdApprovalGate",
  "startTime": "2020-06-01T22:11:53-04:00",
  "lastUpdateTime": "2020-06-01T22:11:53-04:00",
  "status": "InProgress",
  "input": {
    "actionTypeId": {
      "category": "Approval",
      "owner": "AWS",
      "provider": "Manual",
      "version": "1"
    },
    "configuration": {
      "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_COMMIT_ID}",
      "ExternalEntityLink": "#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_URL}",
      "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
    },
    "resolvedConfiguration": {
      "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=xxx1",
      "ExternalEntityLink": "http://",
      "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
    },
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "inputArtifacts": []
  },
  "output": {
    "outputArtifacts": [],
    "outputVariables": {}
  }
}
{
  "pipelineExecutionId": "",
  "actionExecutionId": "",
  "pipelineVersion": 1,
  "stageName": "DeployStage",
  "actionName": "PromoteToProdApprovalGate",
  "startTime": "2020-03-31T23:29:14.479000-04:00",
  "lastUpdateTime": "2020-04-03T19:04:51.646000-04:00",
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "input": {
    "actionTypeId": {
      "category": "Approval",
      "owner": "AWS",
      "provider": "Manual",
      "version": "1"
    },
    "configuration": {
      "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_COMMIT_ID}",
      "ExternalEntityLink": "#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_URL}",
      "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
    },
    "resolvedConfiguration": {
      "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=xxx2",
      "ExternalEntityLink": "http://",
      "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
    },
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "inputArtifacts": []
  },
  "output": {
    "outputArtifacts": [],
    "executionResult": {
      "externalExecutionId": ",
      "externalExecutionSummary": "Approved by arn:aws:sts:"
    },
    "outputVariables": {}
  }
}
{
  "pipelineExecutionId": "",
  "actionExecutionId": "",
  "pipelineVersion": 1,
  "stageName": "DeployStage",
  "actionName": "PromoteToProdApprovalGate",
  "startTime": "2020-03-18T21:10:25.541000-04:00",
  "lastUpdateTime": "2020-03-25T21:10:25.965000-04:00",
  "status": "Failed",
  "input": {
    "actionTypeId": {
      "category": "Approval",
      "owner": "AWS",
      "provider": "Manual",
      "version": "1"
    },
    "configuration": {
      "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_COMMIT_ID}",
      "ExternalEntityLink": "#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_URL}",
      "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1"
    },
    "resolvedConfiguration": {
      "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=xxx3",
      "ExternalEntityLink": "http://",
      "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
    },
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "inputArtifacts": []
  },
  "output": {
    "outputArtifacts": [],
    "executionResult": {
      "externalExecutionId": ""
    },
    "outputVariables": {}
  }
}
{
  "pipelineExecutionId": "",
  "actionExecutionId": "",
  "pipelineVersion": 1,
  "stageName": "DeployStage",
  "actionName": "PromoteToProdApprovalGate",
  "startTime": "2020-03-09T19:23:43.637000-04:00",
  "lastUpdateTime": "2020-03-10T14:48:30.069000-04:00",
  "status": "Failed",
  "input": {
    "actionTypeId": {
      "category": "Approval",
      "owner": "AWS",
      "provider": "Manual",
      "version": "1"
    },
    "configuration": {
      "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_COMMIT_ID}",
      "ExternalEntityLink": "#{SourceBuildVariables.BB_URL}",
      "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1"
    },
    "resolvedConfiguration": {
      "CustomData": "Deploy Service to Prod Approval Required for CommitID=xxx4",
      "ExternalEntityLink": "http://",
      "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:"
    },
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "inputArtifacts": []
  },
  "output": {
    "outputArtifacts": [],
    "executionResult": {
      "externalExecutionId": "",
      "externalExecutionSummary": ""
    },
    "outputVariables": {}
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please delete this post - You can do - `.actionExecutionDetails | sort_by(.startTime) | last` or use `first` if you want the farthest. Remember to post all your requirements in same question next time

Comment: Sure.  I will delete this one.  But I still want to thank you - though it happened I asked one part at a time, since the output for both had different jq query formats, I got to learn two different ways of using jq

Comment: @Inian - I was about to delete this question, but it seems the comment. where you had answered the part about timestamp seems to have been deleted.   I think it is helpful to have your comment someplace.  So, if I delete this question, that information will be lost.  Can you please add it back, so I can delete this question

Comment: Rather than using `sort_by`, it would be more efficient to use `max_by` or `min_by` as appropriate.

Comment: Hi @peak - Can you please put that as an answer so I can accept it? I have added the json for reference to the question. I can do it in my code, but if you put it as answer, it will be helpful to others who are trying to achieve similar functionality with jq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max_by` and provide a path expression,  using which you can sort the array of objects.

```
.actionExecutionDetails
| max_by(.startTime)
```

This is functionally equivalent to doing a sort by the field and get the last element in the array. By default `sort()` function does an ascending sort of the values and does *not* provide an argument to do a descending sort.

```
.actionExecutionDetails
| sort_by(.startTime)
| last
```